# Access reports screw up on different computers

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

I have an access database that I made on my desktop computer at work. I've tried loading the database on my laptop and a different desktop at work, and on both of them the reports are messed up. The reports are too wide and nothing is lined up how it should be. How do I make it so the reports stay the same across all computers?

Comment: They all have the exact same version of Access on them?

Comment: Perhaps you have used some fancy fonts that are not installed on the other systems? Try sticking to standard Arial etc.

Comment: They are all Access 2013, and none of them use any special fonts.

Answer (score 0):

do they have to be loaded from the database or can the reports be opened separately?

i haven't checked lately but there used to be a 'Snapshot Viewer for Microsoft Access' that was great for viewing reports, even without having Access.